# convert to base 64 with A reapeat in result?

Tags: java, android

I get url in android and convert data stream to 64 bit data string with this code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://iranassistance.com/images/sos-logo.png");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
//urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.connect();
File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile();
String filename="downloadedFile.png";
Log.i("Local filename:",""+filename);
File file = new File(SDCardRoot,filename);
if(file.createNewFile()) {
  file.createNewFile();
}
FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();byte[] imageBytes = new byte[urlConnection.getContentLength()];
inputStream.read(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
inputStream.close();
String base64Image = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

But the base64Image result is not complete and gave something like this :

> ......nUTJaJnb7PLyscfBMQLLiexyKSEh/o2RfctcZtc8Hr5xcAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA........

The repeated 'A' show something is wrong and image is not complete! Why this not work properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
inputStream.read(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
```

You assume that the above **always** reads all bytes in one shot.

Wrong. This method reads as many bytes as it wants to read. Therefore it is returning you the **number** of bytes read. See its [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int)):

> Returns: the total number of bytes read into the buffer, or -1 if there is no more data because the end of the stream has been reached.

In other words: you have to **loop** and accumulate these numbers until you got exactly the amount of bytes you are looking for!

And you get those A chars: your array is initially all 0. As explained: you are only filling **parts** of that array. So the rest of the arrays has still 0s in it - which results as AAAAAs after encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to convert image into base64 just pass on your image....

```
private String encodeImage(Bitmap mphoto)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    mphoto.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String encImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

    return encImage;
}
```

Comment: I have to change InputStream to Base64 to save in My database . it does not required to bitmap !

Comment: That is not the problem. The **read** part is wrong. It doesnt help to look at encoding when the bytes to encode are **not complete**.

Comment: when you have the image url so first convert it into bitmap and then you can call on the function

Comment: e.g. URL url = new URL("https://url");
 HttpURLConnection connection1 = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); connection1.setDoInput(true); connection1.connect(); InputStream input1 = connection1.getInputStream(); Bitmap myBitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input1);
 ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); myBitmap1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream1); byte[] byteArray1 = byteArrayOutputStream1 .toByteArray(); encoded1 = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray1, Base64.DEFAULT);

Answer (score 0):

GhostCat said the correct answer ,
i change my code as bellow and it worked find :

```
 InputStream is = null;
    try {

        URL url = new URL("http://iranassistance.com/images/sos-logo.png");
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        is = url.openStream ();
        byte[] byteChunk = new byte[4096]; 
        int n;

        while ( (n = is.read(byteChunk)) > 0 ) {
            baos.write(byteChunk, 0, n);
        }

        String base64Image2 = Base64.encodeToString(baos.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        db.UpdateImage64(base64Image2);
        productModel pd = db.GetProductById(2);

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace ();

    }
    finally {
        if (is != null) {
            try{
                is.close();
            }
                catch (IOException s){

                }
        }
    }
```